# Best way to keep Twitter Bootstrap updated while applying custom css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As asked in the Title, how could I keep a Twitter Bootstrap updated to the latest version from  git or another Version Control (if another ones exist) in minified version (both js and css), while applying some custom styles on it such as:

- Border-radius
- Button colors
- Font-family / Font-size
- etc...

And without using the LESS ?

Anyone who have some clues how to minimize the process to achieve this in the proper way ?

I searched a lot on web, to find out the answer, but no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't modify the bootstrap file.  Just create a second file that adds more specific rules for the things you want to modify.

For example:

```
 #my-app-id .alert {
   background-color: blue;
 }
```

As long as you have a very specific override it will apply *after* bootstrap's rule, leaving the other rules in place.  Then you can simply upgrade boostrap whenever you want.

Also: Reading `less` is *very* simple.  It works the way you imagine that nested CSS would.  You could simply read through the [Bootstrap source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) to figure out the pieces.

---

Alternatively you can just suck it up and use less. It's really simple that way. Checkout bootstrap's master branch.  Change this file:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less

Compile and minify the less to css using one of the many many ways of doing so.

Voilá. Complete.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought for the first time until I realized that the minified bootstrap source css is hard to customize. Any detailed tips maybe ?

Comment: Minified CSS isn't hard to customize at all :) Use the CSS inspector in your web browser to determine what you need to override.  Simple as pie!

Comment: Alternatively just download the unminified CSS and run a preprocesser to merge and minify everything yourself.

Comment: You could also develop with the unminified CSS and then swap it for the same version of minified CSS when you deploy to production.

Comment: correct me if I'am wrong pls: I should keep `bootstrap.css` untouched, create a new one, load it just after the `bootstrap.css`, and make the modificatios across the whole css line by line by finding each elements with inspector ? what if I want to change styles so it will be something like `plusstrap` or Google styles (forms, tables, colors, etc...) ? It ain't gonna be a simple task, right ?

Comment: Leave `Boostrap.css` untouched. Create a new file called `custom_bootstrap.css` (for example).  In that file make *only* the changes you want to make. If you want to add `plusstrap` then add it *after* the **unchanged** bootstrap file.  CSS files happen in order.  Later ones override earlier ones if they have identical selectors.

Comment: There's no way around writing code for everything you want to override.

Comment: @aspirinemaga Just out of curiousity, which way did you decide to go for?

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl - LESS. Download the latest version, unzip `/less` folder and copy inside my `custom.less` which contain necessary variables and mixes collected from the all `/less/*.less` files. Include a less file into `/less/bootstrap.less` by adding our `custom.less` and compile it. When updating, we just download the newest version, and copy/replace into our folder all `.less` files except `bootstrap.less`, and recompile it again, and it's done (Maybe automated this procedure wouldn't hurt each week/or month)

Comment: Depending on what server-side technology you have there's a *large* variety of tools that will automatically compile, optionally squash together, and minify your .less files into one big .css file.  Alternatively your IDE or Text Editor probably has a way of automating it so that it happens whenever you hit a key combo of some sort. (I'm thinking VS or Sublime Text as examples)

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Don't touch the original source.

Just override the CSS rules you need in a custom file.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the new [documentation about the new 3.x](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing) branch you can do it by creating a new CSS file:

> To recap, here's the basic workflow:
>
> - For each element you want to customize, find its code in the compiled
>     Bootstrap CSS. **Copy and paste the selector** for a component as-is.
> - Add all your custom CSS in a **separate stylesheet** using the selectors you
>     just copied from the Bootstrap source. No need for prefacing with
>     additional classes or using !important here.
> - Rinse and repeat until you're happy with your customizations.

The best way is to create a new class name and **use both together**.
For example:

```
<button type="button" class="**btn btn-ttc**">Save changes</button>
```

It uses the original "***btn***" class from bootstrap and add the personalized "***btn-ttc***". So you can add a new CSS file, include it in your project and then create that class:

```
/* Custom button
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Override base .btn styles */
/* Apply text and background changes to three key states: default, hover, and active (click). */
.btn-ttc,
.btn-ttc:hover,
.btn-ttc:active {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #007da7;
}
```